# Rust ndarray - how to set a single element of an element

Tags: rust, multidimensional-array

If I create a 2-dimension `ndarray::Array2` object, how can I set each of the elements of the array (matrix) on an individual basis?

```
use ndarray::Array2;

// ...

// a 10 x 10 element matrix
let my_array = Array2::zeros((10, 10));

// how to set arbitrary elements of the matrix to an arbitrary value?
```

---

I tried creating a `Dim` object, but couldn't figure out how to set the values of each element of it.

I intended to use that in combination with `get_mut`.

```
let index = ndarray::Dim::zeros(2); // 2 dimensional index

my_array.get_mut(&index) = 10.0; // compiler error
```

I'm not sure how the array like object of `ndarray` are supposed to be used in regards to getting and setting elements.

Answer (score 4):

`ndarray` supports all operations expected from an indexable container (a panicking `[]` operator and fallible [`get()`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.get) and [`get_mut()`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.get_mut)). The easiest way to index is to use arrays, one element for each dimension:

```rust
my_array[[0, 0]] = 10.0;
```

You can also index by [`Dim`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.Dim.html) as you tried, but it has to be a static `Dim` and not a dynamic one:

```rust
use num_traits::Zero;

let index = ndarray::Dim::<[ndarray::Ix; 2]>::zero(); // 2 dimensional index

// Or better,
// my_array[index] = 10.0;
*my_array.get_mut(index).unwrap() = 10.0;
```